# Find first and last non-zero column by label in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that is similar to the below with dates as columns and a long list of rows.  The values are numbers.  I want to add a new column that (1) is the label of the index of the first date that appears, and (2) a new column that is the label of the index of the last date that appears.

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)
df = pd.DataFrame({dates[0] : list('000120'),
                dates[1] : list('011501'),
                dates[2] : list('111501'),
                dates[3] : list('011500'),
                dates[4] : list('011001'),
                dates[5] : list('010001')})
```

yielding

```
2013-01-01 2013-01-02 2013-01-03 2013-01-04 2013-01-05 2013-01-06 
0   0   0   1   0   0   0
1   0   1   1   1   1   1
2   0   1   1   1   1   0
3   1   5   5   5   0   0
4   2   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   1   1   0   1   1
```

where the new columns that would be added (just shown here as an example) would be (A is first nonzero value, B is last):

```
index A B    
0 2013-01-03 2013-01-03
1 2013-01-02 2013-01-06
2 2013-01-02 2013-01-05
3 2013-01-01 2013-01-04
4 2013-01-01 2013-01-01
5 2013-01-02 2013-01-06
```

I've tried using various combinations of s.nonzero, lamda functions and searched many posts without coming up with a good answer.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can first convert the DF to bool and find the column index of max on each row, which gives the start date, then reverse the order of columns and find the column index of max on each row again, which gives the end date.

```
df.assign(A=df.astype(int).astype(bool).idxmax(1),\
          B=df.astype(int).astype(bool)[df.columns[::-1]].idxmax(1))
```

Comment: @MaxU This is because a) the DF is of type str and b) we need the first non-0 element not the max element.

Comment: would this work properly: `df.ne('0').assign(A=df.idxmax(1), B=df[df.columns[::-1]].idxmax(1))`?

Answer (score 0):

**Creative Method**
`mask` and `first_valid_index`

```
m = df.mask(df == '0')
fs = [pd.Series.first_valid_index, pd.Series.last_valid_index]
pd.concat([m.apply(f, 1) for f in fs], axis=1, keys=['A', 'B'])

           A          B
0 2013-01-03 2013-01-03
1 2013-01-02 2013-01-06
2 2013-01-02 2013-01-05
3 2013-01-01 2013-01-04
4 2013-01-01 2013-01-01
5 2013-01-02 2013-01-06
```

**`numpy`**-***fi***

```
m = df.values != '0'
c = df.columns.values

first = c[m.argmax(1)]
last = c[m.shape[1] - m[:, ::-1].argmax(1) - 1]

pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([first, last]),
    df.index, ['A', 'B']
)

           A          B
0 2013-01-03 2013-01-03
1 2013-01-02 2013-01-06
2 2013-01-02 2013-01-05
3 2013-01-01 2013-01-04
4 2013-01-01 2013-01-01
5 2013-01-02 2013-01-06
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this using groupby after stacking:

```
>>> d2 = df.astype(int)
>>> stacked = d2.where(d2 != 0).stack().reset_index()
>>> stacked.groupby("level_0")["level_1"].agg(['first', 'last'])
             first       last
level_0                      
0       2013-01-03 2013-01-03
1       2013-01-02 2013-01-06
2       2013-01-02 2013-01-05
3       2013-01-01 2013-01-04
4       2013-01-01 2013-01-01
5       2013-01-02 2013-01-06
```